# Modifying calls in function arguments

Tags: r

How can a function inspect and modify the arguments of a call that it received as argument?

Application: A user feeds a call to function `a` as an argument to function `b`, but they forget to specify one of the required arguments of `a`. How can function `b` detect the problem and fix it?

In this minimal example, function `a` *requires* two arguments:

```r
a <- function(arg1, arg2) {
    return(arg1 + arg2)
}
```

Function `b` accepts a call and an argument. The commented lines indicate what I need to do:

```r
b <- function(CALL, arg3) {
    # 1. check if `arg2` is missing from CALL
    # 2. if `arg2` is missing, plug `arg3` in its place
    # 3. return evaluated call
    CALL
}
```

Expected behavior:

```
b(CALL = a(arg1 = 1, arg2 = 2), arg3 = 3) 
> 3

b(CALL = a(arg1 = 1), arg3 = 3) 
> 4
```

The second call currently fails because the user forgot to specify the required `arg2` argument. How can function `b` fix this mistake automatically?

Can I exploit lazy evaluation to modify the call to `a` before it is evaluated? I looked into [`rlang::modify_call`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/call_modify.html) but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method that would work

```
b <- function(CALL, arg3) {
  scall <- substitute(CALL)
  stopifnot(is.call(scall)) #check that it's a call
  lcall <- as.list(scall)
  if (!"arg2" %in% names(lcall)) {
    lcall <- c(lcall, list(arg2 = arg3))
  }
  eval.parent(as.call(lcall))
}
```

We use `substitute()` to grab the unevaluated version the CALL parameter. We convert it to a list so we can modify it. Then we append to the list another list with the parameter name/value we want. Finally, we turn the list back into a call and then evaluate that call in the environment of the caller rather than in the function body itself.

If you wanted to use `rlang::modify_call` and other `rlang` functions you could use

```
b <- function(CALL, arg3) {
  scall <- rlang::enquo(CALL)
  stopifnot(rlang::quo_is_call(scall))
  if (!"arg2" %in% names(rlang::quo_get_expr(scall))) {
    scall <- rlang::call_modify(scall, arg2=arg3)  
  }
  rlang::eval_tidy(scall, env = rlang::caller_env())
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Bonus points for `is.call` safety.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why fancy language manipulation is needed. The problem is what to do when `a`, which requires 2 arguments, is supplied only 1. Wrapping it with `b`, which has a default value for the 2nd argument, solves this.

```r
b <- function(arg1, arg2=42)
{
    a(arg1, arg2)
}

b(1)
# [1] 43

b(1, 2)
# [1] 3
```

Comment: Because this does not address the fundamental constraint expressed in the original problem: Function `b` does not receive the arguments, it only gets the call. Of course, we could re-write the trivial reproducible example, but in my larger coding project the constraint is impossible to relax. But thanks for taking a look and for your input!